# Class name shows <none> for Ingress Object in local Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes

I'm trying to deploy a simple nginx ingress object in my local kubernetes (Docker-Desktop) but I noticed that the class name is showing as "none" when I do:

```
➜  localk8 k get ingress
NAME               CLASS    HOSTS   ADDRESS     PORTS   AGE
ingress-resource   none   *       localhost   80      15m
```

My ingress definition file is defined as:

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: ingress-resource
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-redirect: "false"
spec:
  rules:
  - http:
      paths:
      - path: /hello
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: hello-app
            port:
              number: 8080
```

I'm also running on a M1 macbook if that makes any difference. Thanks all for the help!

Answer (score 8):

I am not sure what version of kubernetes you're using, but that annotation was [deprecated in 1.18](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress/#deprecated-annotation).

Also, you need to [define an `IngressClass` resource that describes the class](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress/#deprecated-annotation) and then reference it with the new field `ingressClassName`:

```yaml
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: IngressClass
metadata:
  name: nginx
spec:
  controller: example.com/ingress-controller
```

Then in your ingress resource add the new field under spec and reference the class name:

```yaml
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: ingress-resource
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-redirect: "false"
spec:
  // use new field
  ingressClassName: nginx
  rules:
  - http:
      paths:
      - path: /hello
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: hello-app
            port:
              number: 8080
```